# enumerateDevices after getUserMedia: how to find the active devices?

Tags: javascript, getusermedia, mediastream, enumerate-devices

Is there a way to detect which device (camera, microphone) is active, given a `MediaStream` instance?

The app I'm currently working on does simply query for such a stream and attaches it to a `<video/>` element:

```js
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true })

const el = document.querySelector("video")
el.srcObject = stream

console.log(stream.getTracks())
// MediaStreamTrack { kind: "audio", id: "{000d071e-f936-42d8-872e-a568cd96cc2d}", label: "USB Audio Device Mono", … }
​// MediaStreamTrack { kind: "video", id: "{186427d5-b04a-4906-9177-1a088c5d4e0a}", label: "C922 Pro Stream Webcam", …
```

The next step is to give the user the ability to change camera/mic. The basic code for this is:

```js
const devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
console.log(devices)
// MediaDeviceInfo { deviceId: "yQx5+MN7znbmkE0tV98jJHpvqrUaa6Gv5WIXF52jj0s=", kind: "videoinput", label: "C922 Pro Stream Webcam", … }
​// MediaDeviceInfo { deviceId: "dIjwtaOGQbjT2HOqfJ4xjzjXBwBxz4CEeX3a2fn0ZgA=", kind: "audioinput", label: "USB Audio Device Mono", … }​
// MediaDeviceInfo { deviceId: "/t3u7BlfExATtBC4CUmyqIo8RORDxMu9aMrJJHN0Ez0=", kind: "audioinput", label: "C922 Pro Stream Webcam Analog Stereo", … }​
// MediaDeviceInfo { deviceId: "/5pqK1599b+mKHm26zCYQ+Ql3vG0Em7xiVbqfm1C/9A=", kind: "audioinput", label: "Monitor of Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (IEC958)", … }
// MediaDeviceInfo { deviceId: "Tib/PVScFuFUQuAtYYVgtxcxeu08opGKe9MXEVmxq84=", kind: "audioinput", label: "Monitor of USB Audio Device Analog Stereo", … }
```

I can simply transform this list into `<select/>`+`<option/>` lists (one for each `kind`), let the user decide and re-request the stream with the selected `deviceId` (`getUserMedia({ audio: { deviceId: selectedDeviceId } })`).

**However:** the track and device ID don't match, so how do I determine which `<option/>` should be pre-selected? Looking at MDN, the stream's track ID is [generated by the browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/id) (which makes sense), but the [`MediaStream` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream#methods) doesn't provide much alternatives...

Surely, the answer can't be "go by the label"—I can plug in a second identical webcam and have two video devices with the same name?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get the [MediaTrackSettings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackSettings) currently applied on your MediaStreamTracks and check for the `deviceId` from there:

```
const used_devices = mediastream.getTracks()
  .map( (track) => track.getSettings().deviceId );
```

Answer (score -1):

If you do

```
const label = stream.getVideoTracks()[0].label
```

You'll get back the name of the video device. It's an attribute of the [MediaStreamTrack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack) class.

As for the *default* choice, here's how I have figured out which one is the default. (This stinks, but I've found no better way.)

Do a `.getUserMedia({video:true, audio:true})` operation and look at the `label` attributes. That otherwise doltish constraint object chooses the default devices, and by the way gets the user-permission grant completed.

When I say *default device*, I mean the one that's set in browser settings.

Comment: You probably misread the question they clearly explain how "going by the label" is a bad idea.

Comment: No need to copy the content of other answers into yours.